# Akka Tick Completion

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have question on Akka Source Tick

```
Source.tick(initialDelay, interval, listData) ~> flow ~> Sink.foreach(println)
```

How we can find each tick stream processed successfully or not?

Thanks
Arun

Comment: You need to define what means "processed successfully" and how do you want to distinguish ticks. In particular, all ticks by default are the same; you can probably tag them with a timestamp with an additional flow step, but you may want to do something else depending on your requirements. Then, you need to determine what you mean under "processed unsuccessfully". Does this mean some value designating an error or a stream failure?

Comment: thanks Vladimir. The "processed successfully" means how many elements being emitted from tick to flow has been sinked. I would like to know whether all elements from previous tick has been sinked or still in flow. I tried to use materializer and broadcast into separate flow to know the same, but could find the way to read materialised value from one flow to another flow.

Comment: "whether all elements from previous tick has been sinked or still in flow" this doesn't really make sense because a tick always equals to one item in the flow. Your `Source.tick` will yield `listData` as a whole object, even if `listData` is a sequence. Therefore, the only thing you can count is how many times `listData` has been processed by the flow until its failure or completion. The simplest way to do it, I believe, is `map()` paired with `AtomicLong`; I would gladly write an example if this indeed is what you want.